# a4j:commandButton does not invoke action

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss6.x

i am trying to migrate a jsf 1.x richfaces 3.x app to jsf2.x and richfaces 4.x. i have a richpopupPanel inside a form which has a form and two a4j:commandButtons. i am not able to invoke action on the secondbutton to submit the form.

the code goes as follows.

```
<h:form id="outsideform">
     <rich:popupPanel id="details" domElementAttachment="form">
      <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="PopuPTitle" style="text-align: center;" styleClass="center"/>
        </f:facet> 
       <a4j:commandButton id="firstButton" render = "detailsform" action="#{mybean.getDetails()}"/> 

         <h:form id="detailsForm>

           content to be submitted

        <a4j:commandButton id ="secondButton" action ="#{mybean.action()}"  render="addContent"/>

        </h:form>
        </rich:popupPanel>
```

The **detailsForm** renders succesfully on the click of the **firstButton**, but when make some changes in the content and try to submit by clicking on **secondButton** the action on the **secondButton** is not invoked. the form to be submitted is the **detailsForm**.

Comment: As said by @BalusC in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked).
You have not to build a hierarchical form structure when you are managing hierarchical or dependent data.

Comment: @lametaweb  thanks for your response, can you please show me how can i resolve this, because i have to go in this route since i have rich:tabPanel outside the popup  which needs a form surrounding it..

Comment: Its a seam application as well, seam 2.3 is the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use nested `h:form`s. Move "details" popupPanel outside of "outsideform" form.

Comment: your answer worked and there was an issue with backing bean as well, now everything is solved, thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<h:form id="detailsForm>`and add `process="details"` attribute to the second button.

Comment: putting the popupPanel outside the form worked. Actually there was an issue with backing bean as well so was not ivoked, now everything solved. Big Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @Vinay G B you have to accept the other answer, Vasil Lukach answer, not the mine one.

Comment: I found another possible solution using `a4j:region` component. Look at [this page](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=region&skin=blueSky) at Rich Faces showcase site. Line 32 and forward in the sample source code.

Comment: yeah i did something similar to that now its working, thanks again.